# Shorting neutral and earthing trips MCB

Tags: mains, power-electronics

I live in India (220-250V, 50Hz). I have a single phase supply coming into my home. The main MCB trips as expected whenever the Live and Earth conductors get shorted. But I observed that my house's MCB trips even when Neutral and Earth are shorted. Is this standard behaviour or Is my wiring or MCB faulty? How can I check? I have a AC voltage capable Multimeter and an AC clamp meter.

Is it something to do with how MCBs work?

Comment: This question would be a better fit on diy.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Also, the term "MCB" isn't used world-wide. Could you explain what it means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have probably got a [residual current device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual-current_device) built into your MCB. Normal operation is such that current in "live" precisely equals current in "neutral" i.e. no leakage currents through the earth wire.

When you bypass the device, it detects an imbalance in both live and neutral wires and trips: -

[image]

Alternatively the predecessor of the RTD was called an earth leakage detection unit and it actually looked for earth currents above a certain value. These have been superceded by the RCD in a lot of homes.

Comment: US terminology: GFCI. Though a GFCI includes overcurrent protection - therefore really equivalent to RCBO (a combined RCD and MCB)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: Correction: Some GFCIs -- those installed in breaker panels -- have overcurrent protection as well. Other GFCIs are installed in outlets and do not include overcurrent protection.

Comment: MCB stands for Miniature Circuit Breaker, sorry! Thanks for the insights! Makes sense now!